# How to get multiple regex matches in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have this text:

```
 <div class="additional-details">
  <div class="mark-container">
   <input type="checkbox" id="comp-80174649" value="80174649"
          data-heading-code="2550"/>
   <label for="comp-80174649">???</label>
   <a href="#" class="compare-link" id="compare-link-1"
      data-compare="/80174649/2550/"
      data-drop-down-id="compare-content-1"
      data-drop-down-content-id="compare-content"
      data-drop-down-class="drop-down-compare"
      etc...
      data-compare="/8131239/2550/"
```

I am trying to scrape what is inside data-compare="**HERE**" (I have multiple matches).

I know how to do this in C#, using a MatchCollection, but in python I am pretty confused with re.search, re.match and also I've noticed that the regex that is working in C# is not really working in python.

Could somebody explain how to get this done ?

Comment: what is your specific question? i.e. do you want the numbers between the `/` to be extracted as a list?

Comment: well, let's forget about the number, let's say it could be anything (even if now there are numbers). I want to match whatever is between data-compare=" and "

Comment: @roippi Who said that it's XML ? It's basically html. I know I could use some html parser, but I want to use regex in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.findall` can be used to find all the matches in a list.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '<div cla'  # whole string here
>>> result = re.findall('data-compare="([\d/]+)"', s)
>>> print result
['/80174649/2550/', '/8131239/2550/']
```

**Explanation**

The desired output like `'/80174649/2550/'` has only numbers and forward slash, so we'll be only targeting that.

In `([\d/]+)`, `[\d/]` means match either a number (signified by `\d`) or forward slash `/`.

Then the `+` symbol means that the preceding pattern `[\d/]` can occur multiple times since we do have multiple numbers and `/`.

The enclosing parentheses means that the enclosed pattern `[\d/]+` should only be captured and returned.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks. So there is no need for escaping ? Also what does ([\d/]+) mean ?

Comment: No, they don't need to be escaped. You can find the list of special characters that need to be escaped [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). I have edited the answer with an explanation for the regex string I used.